# How do I have to set up Textures that I can use them in an Android OpenGL-ES 2.0 fragment shader?

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I try to access 2 textures in 1 fragment shader.

For this I have 2 textures that I set up with following code:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vbuff);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tbuff);

glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE1_ARB);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1); 
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And I try to combine them with following fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
void main()
{
    vec4 texval1 = texture2D(tex0, TextureCoordOut);
    vec4 texval2 = texture2D(tex1, TextureCoordOut);
    gl_FragColor = 0.5*(texval1 + texval2)
}
```

Somehow this doesn't work and it only displays the second texture.

PS: I am developing the shaders on Windows7 but want to use the C++ code and the shaders with the Android NDK on an Android Device.

**EDIT: I got it working and I post the code here, so that others might benefit from it:**

vertex shader

```
varying vec2 TextureCoordOut;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    TextureCoordOut = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);
}
```

fragment shader

```
varying mediump vec2 TextureCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, TextureCoordOut) * texture2D(tex1, TextureCoordOut);
}
```

render

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vbuff);  //2 dimensional vertex buffer
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, tbuff); // 2 dimensional textures
glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mapid1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mapid2);

glUseProgram(shader);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(gfx.prog, "tex0"), 0);   //GL_TEXTURE0
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(gfx.prog, "tex1"), 1);   //GL_TEXTURE1

render....

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just binding these textures to the respective units is not enough. You also need to tell the shaders where to take the textures for it's `sampler2D` uniforms from. This is done by setting the corresponding integer uniform value to the texture unit you want to use:

```
//get uniform locations (either init code or render code)
int locTex0 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex0");
int locTex1 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex1");

...    

//bind textures to texture units
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);

//bind program and specify texture units for each sampler2D uniform
glUseProgram(program);
glUniform1i(locTex0, 0);   //use texture bound to GL_TEXTURE0
glUniform1i(locTex1, 1);   //use texture bound to GL_TEXTURE1

...
draw
```

Of course this assumes that you know how to use shaders and specify uniform values.

Some additional remarks:

- When using a fragment shader you don't need to call `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`, since the shader decides itself if it uses a texture or not.
- Don't use those ARB versions of functions and constants, at least not for such old and established things like multitexturing, which is core since GL 1.2 or 1.3 (~15 years).
- Don't expect your code to be 1-to-1 portable to OpenGL ES 2.0, which doesn't know about the old builtin attributes (like `glVertexPointer` or `glTexCoordPointer`), but that is a different question.